# Is every c.c.c. non-atomic partial order of size $\omega_1$ a union of countable complete suborders?

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

We say that  $\mathbb{P}$ is a complete suborder of $\mathbb{Q}$, if it is a suborder, and maximal antichains in $\mathbb{P}$ remain maximal antichains in $\mathbb{Q}$

As the title says, is every c.c.c. non-atomic partial order of size $\omega_1$ a union of countable complete suborders?

If the answer is no, are there some common c.c.c. forcings which are this way? eg. Suslin trees.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't every poset be a union of its two-element suborders?

Comment: Two element suborders wouldn't necessarily be complete suborders. I edited the question to include the definition of complete suborder.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248291/is-every-c-c-c-non-atomic-partial-order-of-size-omega-1-a-union-of-countable

Comment: Question was answered at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248291

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives in my opinion very reasonable advice about cross-posting. You might also have a look at some of the other posts tagged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]).

Comment: You say you have received answer at the other site. I am not sure what the best course of action now should be. Maybe you could answer this copy question yourself, with a link and brief summary of the answer on MO. But leaving this question [as unanswered](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/unanswered-questions/info) on this site is definitely not a good way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered at mathoverflow.net/questions/248291